# How can I execute some code if jQuery dialog was closed on escape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog and I need to execute `some_code()` when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button. The latter is easy to implement, I just add define a property of the `buttons` object:

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({

  closeOnEscape: true,

  close: function(event, ui) {
    //some_code();
    $(this).dialog('destroy')
  },

  buttons: {
    "OK": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
      some_code();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

But how can I execute `some_code()` after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>? This function must not be called clicking the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, so I cannot simply place it in the `close` event.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After googling around without finding an answer, I started looking into `close: function(event, ui)` part and found the solution using `event.originalEvent` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/MXk3a/2)):

```js
close: function(event, ui) {
  // some_code();
  if (event.originalEvent) {
    // triggered by clicking on dialog box X or pressing ESC
    // not triggered if a dialog button was clicked
    some_code();
  }
  $(this).dialog('destroy')
}
```